# Excel Vba copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba

While copying data from one Excel sheet to another workbook I have to paste data with the same format because each cell has interior color. I will also delete the data from the original sheet which I copied from. Is it possible to keep the source formatting?

```
Workbooks.Add
Set Outbook1 = ActiveWorkbook
OutBook.Activate
OutBook.Sheets("Sheet6").Select
Lines = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A1:N" & Lines).Select
Selection.Copy

Outbook1.Activate
Outbook1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the source formatting (as long as it's not conditional formatting), using the `PasteSpecial xlPasteAll` command.

**Recommendation**: It's always better if you stay from `Activate` , `Select` and `Selection`, instead use referenced `Workbook`s and `Sheets`.

(for more details go to [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) )

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyBetweenSheets()

Dim Outbook1        As Workbook
Dim OutBook         As Workbook
Dim Lines           As Long

Set OutBook = ThisWorkbook
Set Outbook1 = Workbooks.Add

With OutBook
    With .Sheets("Sheet6")
        ' find last row in Column A in "Sheet6"
        Lines = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:N" & Lines).Copy
    End With
End With

' paste to "A1" in "Sheet1" in the new workbook
Outbook1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

End Sub
```

Comment: still color of each row is not copied to new workbook

Comment: @yuvaraj  what color? Are u referring to conditional formatting?

Comment: @yuvaraj it's ok :) and thanks for accepting my answer